# How to start a beginner with a Nordic nRF52810 bluetooth 5.0 module

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, nrf52

I need to use an STM32F4 MCU with Laird BL651 Bluetooth 5.0 module.
As I realized this module is not the regular simple AT Command module, but rather a Cortex-M microcontroller (Nordic nRF52810) with BT Stack. I have a 1.5 year experience with STM32 and the Cube firmware package, but have no experience either Bluetooth 5.0 nor Nordic products. So my question is basically, how to start the developement. I have found Nordic SDK but I am clueless, what information I will need hierinafter and where can I found sample codes.

Looking forward for the replies.

Thanks

Samu

Comment: Learn RTOS as a starting point

Comment: Surly it depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As with most embedded development, your first step is to get any simple (prewritten) example to work, and then after that start either tailoring that example to your use case or creating a new one from scratch. For the BL651 you'll need to read up a bit on the Nordic SDK as well as Bluetooth Low Energy in general. Below are some useful references that will help you get started:-

**Bluetooth Low Energy References**

- [Bluetooth Low Energy: A Primer](https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-a-primer?utm_sq=g7jck8212t&utm_source=LinkedIn&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=PhillipJohnston&utm_content=Linkstoshare)
- [Getting Started with Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch01.html)
- [Introduction to BLE](https://www.mikroe.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-part-1-introduction-ble)

**Nordic Development References**

- [nRF5 Getting Started](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fstruct_nrf5gs%2Fstruct%2Fnrf5gs.html&cp=1)
- [nRF5 Series: Developing with SEGGER Embedded Studio](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fug_gsg_ses%2FUG%2Fgsg%2Fintro.html&cp=1_1_0)
- [Introduction to Nordic SDK v16.0.0](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fstruct_nrf5gs%2Fstruct%2Fnrf5gs_sw_dev.html&cp=1_1)

I hope this helps.